# Telerik Kendo UI with SharePoint List Items

Tags: sharepoint, telerik, kendo-grid, odata, telerik-grid

I am trying to create a grid using Telerik Kendo UI which will show SharePoint data. To fetch data I am using SharePoint oData service.

I got an example of similar functionality here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding

And tried below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/remote-data-binding">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://server/_api/Web/Lists(guid'guid of list')/Items"
                            },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        Title: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 20,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        filterable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        columns: [{
                                field:"Title"
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
            </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And got below error

> Refused to execute script from
> 'http://server/_api/Web/Lists(guid'listguid50387715207_1459178447636&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24format=json&%24top=20'
> because its MIME type ('application/atom+xml') is not executable, and
> strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: Seems that the url you are pointing to isn't using a compatible MIME type.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to change the transport-property to

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "http://server/_api/Web/Lists(guid'guid of list')/Items",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json; odata=verbose")
        }
    }
}
```

in order to force sharepoint to return json-data instead of atom+xml (which is the default if you ommit the accept-header).